# remove custom error messages on successful validation for each field

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I tried with error Container also with reset Form() function but its not giving desired result.
Also I am using show Errors to display error

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
  console.log("Errors:" + langCode);
  $.each(errorList, function(key, value) {
    console.log("ErrorList:" + langCode);
    $("#" + value.element.id + "Error").html();
    var errorMsg = errorJson[langCode][value.element.id][value.method];
    // var errorMsg = errorJson[langCode][value.element.id][value.method];
    $("#" + value.element.id + "Error").html(errorMsg);
  });
}
```

Jquery validation plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: jquery validation plugin https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: What is the desired result, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: when I am using errorContainer its showing default error messages and gets clear when field is valid ..But I want same functionality for customised messages ie hide error message as soon as field gets validated.For  example "minlength": 3, after entering 3 characters error message should get cleared .

Answer (score 0):

use success block for hiding your custom error message

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
  console.log("Errors:" + langCode);
  $.each(errorList, function(key, value) {
    console.log("ErrorList:" + langCode);
    $("#" + value.element.id + "Error").html();
    var errorMsg = errorJson[langCode][value.element.id][value.method];
    // var errorMsg = errorJson[langCode][value.element.id][value.method];
    $("#" + value.element.id + "Error").html(errorMsg);
  });
},
success: function(label, element) {
      var element = $(element);
      ("#"+element.id+"Error").html();
    }
```

Comment: You should ask that as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: thank you for reply ,I tried success block too but its not working .